# VueJS - Component not displaying unless a selection is made on the drop down menu

Tags: vue.js

I am having an issue whereby my results do not display when the page loads. It will only display if i make a selection on the drop-down menu.

I have tried adding the function to the mounted property but that doesn't seem to work. Any ideas what this might be?

```
                <select v-model="sortResults"
                @change="sortalphabetically"
                class="col-4 col-lg-5"
                aria-label="sortby"
                id="sortby">
                 <option disabled value="" selected>Select</option>  
                <option value="alpha">Alphabetically</option>
                <option value="relevance">Relevance</option>
              </select>

methods: {     
    sortalphabetically() {
      switch (this.sortResults) {
        case "alpha":
          this.theResults = [...this.results].sort((a, b) =>
            a.metaData.title > b.metaData.title ? 1 : -1
          );
          break;
        case "relevance":
          this.theResults = [...this.results];
          break;
      }
    },
  }

 data: function () {
    return {      
      sortResults: "relevance"
}
```

import Result from "@/components/Result.vue";

```
 mounted() {    
    this.dataFilters;
    this.updateURL();
    this.theResults();
    
  },
};
```

Comment: Here I am agian! :D Good you made a new question, however can you show how you tried it do with the mounted()?

Comment: Hello! @Wimanicesir, good to hear from you again. I have added the mounted code.  I did have a little trial and error with this too. Any help appreciated. I know it is difficult when you can see all the code. Thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reproduced your code by adding some changes and it works correctly.

First, you do not sort your values in the second switch's case. It maybe is your business :-) It doesn't matter.

Second, in showing results if you are using `v-if` please do not use `i` as the index of the result array for its key, It won't work. Vue and even React do not recognise the changing order of an array if its index is being used as the key. So, use the items' unique ids.

```js
<template>
  <div>
    <select
      id="sortby"
      aria-label="sortby"
      class="col-4 col-lg-5"
      v-model="sortResults"
      @change="sortalphabetically"
    >
      <option disabled value="" selected>Select</option>
      <option value="alpha">Alphabetically</option>
      <option value="relevance">Relevance</option>
    </select>
    <div style="background-color: aquamarine">
      <div
        v-for="item in theResults" :key="item.metaData.id"
       >
        {{item.metaData.title}}
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'BaseSelectTest',

  data() {
    return {
      sortResults: 'relevance',
      theResults: [],
      results: [
        { metaData: { title: 'BBBB', id: 2 } },
        { metaData: { title: 'DDDD', id: 4 } },
        { metaData: { title: 'AAAA', id: 1 } },
        { metaData: { title: 'CCCC', id: 3 } },
        { metaData: { title: 'EEEE', id: 5 } },
      ],
    };
  },
  methods: {
    sortalphabetically() {
      switch (this.sortResults) {
        case 'alpha':
          this.theResults = [...this.results]
            .sort((a, b) => (a.metaData.title > b.metaData.title ? 1 : -1));
          break;
        case 'relevance':
          this.theResults = [...this.results] // You may omit the next line
          // .sort((a, b) => (a.metaData.title > b.metaData.title ? -1 : 1));
          break;
        default:
          // nothing left to do
      }
    },
  },
  mounted() {
    this.sortalphabetically(); // It's optional if you ignore sorting for 'relevance'
  },
};
</script>
```

Finally, if your flaw persists, you need to check out the showing result codes. Of course, it's possible to observe data changes using the Vue Dev Tool for sure.

Comment: Thanks! Hmm, I have this code and its still not working. It is displaying the data as it shows displaying 100 results and if i look in the console I can see the results also. They just don't display! I will pick through the code. It must be something silly that I doing. Thanks a million again for your help & time.